# How to make a report through multiple table join at a given date in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery, report

I have a few basics in SQL (mostly for spatial analysis with PostGIS) but I want to make a small Access DB to manage data about members in a small organisation. The DB in structured like that :

| Members |
| --- |
| id |
| attribut1 |
| attribut2 |
| attribut3 |

linked by memberId to

| Attribut4 | Attribut5 | Attribut6 | Attribut7 | Attribut8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| memberId | memberId | memberId | memberId | memberId |
| changeDate | changeDate | changeDate | changeDate | changeDate |
| a4Value1 | a5Value1 | a6Value1 | a7Value1 | a8Value1 |
| a4Value2 | a5Value2 | a6Value2 | a7Value2 | a8Value2 |

The goal here is to get the a*N*Value*M* for each member at a given date.
Something like that :

id, attribut1, attribut2, attribut3, a4Value1, a5Value1, a5Value2, a6Value1, a7Value1, a8Value2

I managed to make it work for a single member in a form where I give the id and the date, but the struggle appears when I try to make it work to list every member. I tried with subqueries without success, and peculiarities from Access doesn't help my little knowledge in SQL.

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      *,
      row_number() OVER(
        PARTITION BY Members.id
        ORDER BY
          Members.id,
          Attribut4.changeDate DESC,
          Attribut5.changeDate DESC,
          Attribut6.changeDate DESC,
          Attribut7.changeDate DESC,
          Attribut8.changeDate DESC
      ) AS rn
    FROM
      (
        (
          (
            (
              (
                Members
                LEFT JOIN Attribut4 ON Members.id = Attribut4.id
              )
              LEFT JOIN Attribut8 ON Members.id = Attribut8.id
            )
            LEFT JOIN FONCT_FORM ON Members.id = FORM.id
          )
          LEFT JOIN Attribut7 ON Members.id = Attribut7.initiales
        )
        LEFT JOIN Attribut5 ON Members.id = Attribut5.initiales
      )
      LEFT JOIN Attribut6 ON Members.id = Attribut6.initiales
    WHERE
      (
        (
          (Attribut4.changeDate) <= FORM.date
        )
        AND (
          (Attribut5.changeDate) <= FORM.date
        )
        AND (
          (Attribut6.changeDate) <= FORM.date
        )
        AND (
          (Attribut7.changeDate) <= FORM.date
        )
        AND (
          (Attribut8.changeDate) <= FORM.date
        )
      )
  ) sub
WHERE
  rn = 1;
```

The next step would be to make a form to update the last state, and add rows with changeDate for the modified attributes.

Maybe I overestimate my capabilities, but it's an example of small task I love to try myself for improvement or just out of curiosity and interest.

EDIT : [here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/jf5szst5glmfpb2yihyje/h?dl=0&rlkey=yls7oxyi13mdix7dzl81yx6tu) is a quick data sample

Comment: `row_number() OVER( ...  PARTITION BY` isn't included in Access SQL.

Comment: Second table does not appear to be normalized structure. Edit question to show desired output based on given sample. Would be nice to use realistic data.

Comment: And what is COLLAB?

Comment: Thanks for your first responses. I made a few edits :)

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access, the WHERE criteria is applies *after* the LEFT JOIN, so it is knocking out the entire row if even one related record is not present. In some other  RDBMS's, it is applied before.
Hence you'd have to either create a query for each attribute table to apply the WHERE, or join on a subquery like this:

```
FROM Members
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Attribut4 a4 WHERE a4.changeDate<= FORM.date) Attribut4
  ON Members.id = Attribut4.id
```

etc.
I'm not sure that Access will cope with this amount of inline subquerying, but breaking the subqueries out to query objects should work.

And @Gustav is right, the PARTITION feature is MSSQL specific. You could use it with an ODBCDirect workspace, but for native MS Access or linked MSSQL tables, it won't work.